# Overlapped div when printing a page

Tags: asp.net

I have an old ASP page that renders a series of divs using asp:Repeater. It looks fine when rendered on a page. But when I run window.print(), the preview contains overlapped items at the end of pages, in which, the overlapped item is rendered again on the next page.

My CSS for the div container for each item is:

```
@media print {
    div.report-content {
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
        page-break-before: auto !important;
        page-break-after: auto !important;
        display: table !important;
    }
}
```

The page rendered just fine like this screenshot:
[image]

But when running window.print(), this is what I got:
[image]

Notice that the item named **aaa, bbb** is pushed up and rendered right after the name portion of item **111, Assassin**, causing both (and subsequent items after aaa, bbb) to overlap. Then, on the next page, the item **aaa, bbb** is rendered again, complete with all overlapped items.

Any idea why? Any possible explanations are welcomed. I've been looking any similar cases with no avail.

Oh, right. This only happens on Edge and Chrome. It doesn't happen on Firefox, Safari, and Opera.